# Help with sigma and Π calculation

Tags: functions, notation

I am currently working on final project with WASPAS procedure where the determination of lambda include Π in the calculation. Does anyone could help to solve this equation? I have tried for more than an hour and still havent figure it out.

[image: Click to see the equation]

$\sigma^2(x_{ij})= (0.05x_{ij})^2$

The example in the journal for the data is this
$w_1 = 0.467$ $w_2= 0.160$ $w_3= 0.095$ and $w_4 = 0.278$
$x_{11} = 0.837$ $x_{12}= 0.8389$ $x_{13}= 1$ and $x_{14}= 0.8594$

using only these $8$ data it could obtain the $\sigma^2(Q_i)^2 =0.8578$
I still have no idea how to use the equation to obtain that number.

Your help will be very appreciated!
I still could not copy an image as my point is below $10$, please kindly click the link to see the equation

Comment: What are you trying to solve for? I don't think it's possible to isolate any of the variables

Comment: I am trying to solve equation in this journal https://www.mii.lt/Informatica/pdf/INFO1022.pdf

Comment: I mean this journal https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276466105_Applications_ofWASPAS_Method_in_Manufacturing_Decision_Making

Comment: I don't understand what "solve the equation" means in this context

Comment: Oops my bad, I mean how to use the equation, I am not familiar with Π notation. Using the w1, w2, w3, w4 and x11, x12, x13, x14 provided, it should produce  σ2(Qi)2=0.8578, but I do not understand how to input the number to the equation.

Comment: Please copy the formula carefully.  It seems wrong (or, at best, confusing) to have index $j$ on both $\sum$ and $\prod$.  Also, are $x_{ij}$ and $\overline{x}_{ij}$ related somehow?